# Response 411 Length Required in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm starting in Gatling. I have 411 status and don't understand why.

```
Response DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 16:07:51 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0

19:07:53.083 [gatling-http-thread-1-2] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager - Closing Channel [id: 0x5f14313e, L:/10.8.1.89:52767 - R:blabla.com:5000] 
19:07:53.107 [gatling-http-thread-1-2] INFO io.gatling.commons.validation.package$ - Boon failed to parse into a valid AST: -1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
...
19:07:53.111 [gatling-http-thread-1-2] WARN io.gatling.http.ahc.ResponseProcessor - Request 'HTTP Request createCompany' failed: status.find.is(200), but actually found 411
19:07:53.116 [gatling-http-thread-1-2] DEBUG io.gatling.http.ahc.ResponseProcessor -
```

My code:

```
package load
import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class LoadScript extends Simulation{

 val httpConf = http
  .baseURL("http://blabla.com:5000")
  .authorizationHeader("Bearer 35dfd7a3c46f3f0bc7a2f06929399756029f47b9cc6d193ed638aeca1306d")
  .acceptHeader("application/json, text/plain,")
  .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")
  .acceptLanguageHeader("ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
  .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36")

 val basicLoad = scenario("BASIC_LOAD").exec(BasicLoad.start)

 setUp(
   basicLoad.inject(rampUsers(1) over (1 minutes))
  .protocols(httpConf))
 }

 object BasicLoad {
   val start =
   exec(
    http("HTTP Request createCompany")
      .post("/Companies/CreateCompanyAndStartTransaction")
      .queryParam("inn","7733897761")
      .queryParam("ogrn","5147746205041")
      .check(status is 200, jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("idCompany"))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sending message-body you need to add
`.header("Content-Length", "0")` as workaround.
I have similar issue. I'm running my tests on two environments and a difference is in application infrastructure.
Tests are passing on Amazon AWS but getting HTTP 411 on Azure. So looks like the issue is not in Gatling itself.

This issue has been also well answered by Gatling team at the and of this chat:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/mAGzjzoMr1I

Comment: @FrankerZ I updated my response. It solved my problem and there is a link to good explanation

Comment: I've just upgraded Gatling from 2.3 to 3.0.2 which seems to fix the issue by this line:
https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/15c370b50cd85831a3a248c15b287e890a79d9e4/gatling-http-client/src/main/java/io/gatling/http/client/impl/request/WritableRequestBuilder.java#L45
but it doesn't work for all may cases. Don't know yet why.

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded Gatling from 2.3 to 3.0.2. They wrote their own HTTP client and it sends now content-length: 0 except one case described in this bug:
https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3648

so if you avoid using httpRequest() with method type passed as string e.g:

```
exec(http("empty POST test").httpRequest("POST","https://gatling.io/"))
```

and use post() as you do:

```
exec(
http("HTTP Request createCompany")
  .post("/Companies/CreateCompanyAndStartTransaction")...
```

or

```
exec(
http("HTTP Request createCompany")
  .httpRequest(HttpMethod.POST, "/Companies/CreateCompanyAndStartTransaction")
```

then upgrade Gatling to 3.0.2 is enough. Otherwise you need to wait for Gatling 3.0.3